Movie where one sister feeds a second one with sandwiches with earthworm
I'm looking for the movie which:

was made in 80' (probably, I have seen it really long time ago),
probably it was english language movie,
I think one sister was paralyzed, and the second one took care of her,
I dont remember the reason, but the relation was toxic. Sick sister was fed once with sandwiches with earthworms, another time with the meal prepared from her dog.


This sounds a lot like the remake of "Whatever Happened to Baby Jane?" that was on TV in 1991. It starred the Redgrave sisters (Vanessa and Lynn). The story involves one sister (Jane) taking care of her paralyzed sister (Blanche). 
In the story, the sisters were both famous child actors, but Blanche eventually became more famous. Jane was jealous (and a bit crazy) and attempted kill Blanche, but ended up paralyzing her instead. Jane then tortured Blanche by, among other things, feeding her food with worms. 
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Ever_Happened_to_Baby_Jane%3F_(1991_film)

I saw this as a parody in a show called "Popular" but i didn't know which movie it was from untill you posted it. image from the episode

It seems that I have seen the older version, from 1962.
